# Problem on shuffling the order of created divs

Tags: javascript, object

I asked about how to shuffle the order of some created divs in JS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270532/shuffle-the-order-of-created-divs-js). And one person answered me, but when I do what he told me some divs aren't shown and other appear twice. How can I do to shuffle the order automatically on refresh without having these problems? Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is. You seem to fetch the data correctly, and you were pointed to some bulletproof answers for shuffling arrays, not sure how that could go wrong.

Comment: Instead of playing "go around internet" game, please add the relevant code to the question, and explain in details, what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Some elements appear twice"** means you did **something wrong with the shuffle**. If you can paste the full code. I don't know how you did the shuffle but try something below,

```
var dbUsers = firebase.database().ref('...');

dbUsers.on('value', gotData1, errData1);

function gotData1(data) {
    var users = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(users);

    // Shuffle 'keys' here
    shuffledKeys = shuffle(keys);

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var k = keys[i];
        var name = users[k].name;

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'div');

        var usersPre = document.createElement('pre');
        usersPre.textContent = name;
        div.appendChild(usersPre);

    };
}
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;
    var temporaryValue;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Do you know how can I do to make it work when clicking a button?

Comment: @Unaidu I don't really get what you ask. Can you please try first and post a different question if it doesn't work ?